# How to play a sound that was imported into C# WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, audio

I have an issue with trying to play sound in my WPF application. When I reference the sound from its actual file location, like this,

```
private void playSound()
    {
        //location on the C: drive
        SoundPlayer myNewSound = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\...\sound.wav");
        myNewSound.Load();
        myNewSound.Play();
    }
```

it works fine. However, I recently imported the same sound into my project, and when I try to do this,

```
private void playSound()
    {
        //location imported in the project
        SoundPlayer myNewSound = new SoundPlayer(@"pack://application:,,,/sound.wav");
        myNewSound.Load();
        myNewSound.Play();
    }
```

it produces an error and the sound won't play. How can I play the sound file imported into my project?

Comment: What is the error?  Can you add it to the post as an edit?

Comment: What do you mean by imported ? What you have done ?

Comment: The error that pops up is: "An unhandled exception of type System.NotSupportedException occurred in System.dll"

Comment: "Additional information: The URI prefix is not recognized."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `pack Uri` as argument, but it needs either a `Stream` or a `filepath` .

As you have added the file to your project, so change its `Build Action to Content` , and `Copy To Output Directory to Always`.

```
using (FileStream stream = File.Open(@"bird.wav", FileMode.Open))
    {
        SoundPlayer myNewSound = new SoundPlayer(stream);
        myNewSound.Load();
        myNewSound.Play();
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me, although it should be noted that I had to add `using System.IO;` first. Other than that, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Easiest/shortest way for me is to change **Build Action** of added file to **Resource**, and then just do this:

```
   SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.sound_file);//sound_file is name of your actual file
   player.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with reflection.

Set the property *Build Action* of the file to *Embedded Resource*.

You can then read it with:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExcetutingAssembly();
string name = "Namespace.Sound.wav";
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name))
{
    SoundPlayer myNewSound = new SoundPlayer(stream);
    myNewSound.Load();
    myNewSound.Play();
}
```